# Get extra details via pipe operator with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my service, I want get one object but I also want the details of that single object before I return it to my component.

Using the pipe operator I try to call the function that would provide me the details (in this case `Bar`).

But I'm a bit lost how I would do this, since I return `observable<Bar>` and not a `Bar`.

```
export class Foo {
  public ID;
  public Bar: Bar;
}

export class Bar { }

  /**
  * Returns a single Foo
  */
  public FindSingleFoo(fooID: string): Observable<Foo | HttpError> {
    return this._httpClient.post<Foo>('API/FindSingleFoo', fooID)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => this.FindBarOfFoo(data)),
      );
  }

   /**
   * Returns the Bar of Foo
   * @param fooID - the ID you want Bar for
   */
  public FindBarOfFoo(foo: Foo): Observable<Foo | HttpError> {
    return this._httpClient.post<Bar>('API/FindBarOfFoo', foo.ID).subscribe(
      (result: Bar) => foo.Bar = result
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using [**`switchMap`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) instead of [**`map`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Give this a try:

```
export class Foo {
  public ID;
  public Bar: Bar;
}

export class Bar {}

import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public FindSingleFoo(fooID: string): Observable<Bar|HttpError> {
  return this._httpClient.post<Foo>('API/FindSingleFoo', fooID)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(data => this.FindBarOfFoo(data)),
    );
}

public FindBarOfFoo(foo: Foo): Observable <Bar|HttpError> {
  return this._httpClient.post<Bar>('API/FindBarOfFoo', foo.ID);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this i think this will work

```
public FindSingleFoo(fooID: string): Observable<Foo> {
    return this._http.post<Foo>('API/FindSingleFoo', fooID)
        .pipe(
            map((data) => this.FindBarOfFoo(data)),
            //map(data => data)
        );
}

/**
* Returns the Bar of Foo
* @param fooID - the ID you want Bar for
*/
public FindBarOfFoo(foo: Foo): Foo {
    let X = null;
    this._http.post<Bar>('API/FindBarOfFoo', foo.ID).subscribe(
        data => { X = data }
    );
    return X;
}
```

Comment: having a function encapsulate an observable, invoke `subscribe()` on it and not return the subscription is a bad practice. You should return the observable stream so the callee can decide when to make it hot and when it is no longer interested. This will also help in preventing memory leaks